# Асинхронность в fetch

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

Я так понимаю что асинхронно так не отработает или я что-то делаю не так?

```js
async function getData(url='') {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        method: 'GET'
    });
    return await response.json();
}

console.log(1);
getData('/foo')
.then((data) => {
    console.log(2);
});
console.log(3);
```

Никак не заставить выполнятся последовательно?

Comment: [для ноды](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), а вообще ажаксом можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последовательно такая конструкция работать не будет.

```js
async function getData(url = '') {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    method: 'GET'
  });
  // Нет тут никакого JSON
  return await response.json();
}

console.log(1);
getData('/foo')
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(2);
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log('Error: И все тут работает');
  });
console.log(3);

// Только так
void async function() {
  try {
    await getData('/foo')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Первое сообщение')
  }
  console.log('... второе')
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

В javascript каждый promise выполняется в следующей итерации, так устроен event-loop. Всегда нужно ждать вылолнения промиса. Обязательно посмотри [видео #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cV4ZvHXQL4), [видео #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4_9BZezSUA) на эту тему

Promise:

```js
fetch('/foo', {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  method: 'GET'
}).then((response) => {
   // ждем тут
   сonsole.log(1);
   return response.json();
}).then((data) => {
   // ждем тут
   сonsole.log(2);
}).then(() => {
   // ждем тут
   сonsole.log(3);
});
```

async/await

```js
async function getData(url) {
    // ждем тут
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      method: 'GET'
    });

    сonsole.log(1);

    return response.json();
}

// асинхронные функции всегда возвращают промис
// мы должны его тоже ждать как и в примере выше
getData('/foo').then((data) => {
   // ждем тут
   сonsole.log(2);
}).then(() => {
   // ждем тут
   сonsole.log(3);
});
```

или

```js
async function getData(url) {
    // ждем тут
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      method: 'GET'
    });

    сonsole.log(1);

    // ждем тут
    const data = await response.json();

    сonsole.log(2);
}

// асинхронные функции всегда возвращают промис
getData('/foo').then((data) => {
   // ждем тут
   сonsole.log(3);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Я обычно так удовлетворяюсь:

```js
const afetch=(_url)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            async: true,
        }).done((r)=>{
            if(!r)r = false;
            resolve(r);
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e.status, e.responseText, e);
            resolve(false);
        });
    });
};

(async()=>{
    let r = await afetch('http://google.com/');

    // code, any work with response

    console.log('response', r);
})();
```

пс я знаю що можно `await $.ajax`, но оно работает раз через раз (не устраивает)