# POST-запрос к GAS из javasrcipt

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать? Раньше пользовался GET-запросом, но иногда не хватает длины строки url.
Пробовал вот так но не получается, и не пойму как отладить WEB-исполняемый скрипт:

```
try {
    const response = fetch(scripturl, {
        method: 'POST', 
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // данные м
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    const json = response.json();
    console.log('Успех:', JSON.stringify(json));
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка:', error);
}
```

Comment: ... и не получится, `fetch(...)` возвращает `Promise`, использовать его можно внутри асинхронной функции. Примерно так `await fetch(...)`.

Comment: Alexander Lonberg на await fetch(...). ругается расширение chrome (в котором и пишется код) сразу после его загрузки. Точнее хром после загрузки расширения

Comment: Так вы его в асинхронную функцию завернули? Chrome на такое ругаться не может и не будет.

Comment: самый простой пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1125535/305162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const fetchData = async (scripturl, data) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(scripturl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data), // данные м
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const json = response.json();
        console.log('Успех:', JSON.stringify(json));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка:', error);
    }
}
fetchData(scripturl, data)
```

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало отлично. Если бы раньше знал, что можно посмотреть запросы\ответы в Хроме, сэкономил бы массу времени: https://qna.habr.com/q/733989